# Write selected GridView data to a TextBox on another Webpage C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Gridview on a webpage which is populated with data fed from a XML file, the gridview also contains a checkbox column. I have another page which has a textbox placed on it. I require to send the selected rows from the gridview to the textbox on the other page by the click of a button.

[image]
The screenshot above is the gridview of the items being fed from an xml file. I require the checked rows of the gridview to be displayed in a textbox, which is displayed on another page of the web application, and this is to be done by clicking the 'Send Items' button. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are both pages part of the same application? Then you could use something like SignalR to send the data to the other page and update the textbox.